# Laravel Blade : how do i make textarea show on clicking add more

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this school application, I want to add 100 questions to the database, the normal thing done is add, one after the other., that is I will click submit 100 times....exhausting right.... Now, I want to create an application that I will have to query the database once, that is the submit button will have an add more button beside, but if I click to add more, it should make another text area show below......but if I click save, it should save to the database

```
<form method="post"  action={{route('save.question', $subject->slug)}} >
@csrf
        <textarea name="questions"></textarea>

        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        <button type=''>Add more question</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some approaches, but I prefer:

1. If click on `Add more question` button, add a textarea input to DOM
2. If click on `Submit`, add all textarea values to a javascript array
3. Stringify the array
4. Send it into an input that hidden
5. Decode that input value in PHP with `json_decode()`

So:

```js
let questionsContainer = document.querySelector("#questions-container");
let addQuestionTextarea = document.querySelector("#add-question-textarea");

addQuestionTextarea.onclick = () => {
    let textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    questionsContainer.appendChild(textarea);
}

let submit = document.querySelector("#submit");
submit.onclick = () => {
    collectValues();
}

function collectValues(){
    let allTextareas = questionsContainer.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
  allTextareas = [...allTextareas]
  let allValues = [];
  allTextareas.forEach((textarea)=>{ allValues.push(textarea.value) });
  
  document.getElementById('questions-array').value = JSON.stringify(allValues);
  document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
```

```css
textarea{
    display:block;
    margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="questions-container">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>

<button id="add-question-textarea">Add more question</button>


<form method="post"  action={{route('save.question', $subject->slug)}} id="form">
@csrf
    <input type="text" id="questions-array" hidden name="questions">
</form>
 <button id="submit">Submit</button>
```